# Angular 2 <base> tag and svg not render properly

Tags: angular, svg

When Routing & Navigation the Angular page by giving (base href="/"), the svg object render black in mac book.

Comment: With which browser and which version of that browser?

Comment: safari with latest version

Comment: That's how href used to be interpreted (and still is by Safari). Because users found that confusing the specification was changed, I guess Safari will catch up one day. In the meantime do none of the other Q&A on this topic solve your problem? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732937/angular-2-dart-svg-path-marker-not-displaying-what-is-missing